# Emulate Xiaomi device Genymotion or Android Studio

Tags: android, genymotion, xiaomi

I'm having a problem with my application on mobile XIAOMI POCOPHONE phones only. I would like to emulate this specific device, since the problem is occurring in the clients device and I haven't physical access to them. (I also have no idea what problem is occurring, because the application is simply closing).

Someone has been through something or was able to emulate this device on cross platform?

TU

Answer (score 0):

You can use Genymotion to emulate the resolution, memory, cores, dpi, Android version etc of the device that is causing the crash. In most cases you can replicate the crash. This is the first thing I would try.